# Not able to connect to DBCS from SQL developer

Tags: database, ssh, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to connect to `oracle cloud database` from `SQL developer`. for which I am creating `ssh tunneling`. But I am getting error.

```
`158.101.174.46` is `public IP address` and `10.0.0.2` is `private IP address`.
```

[image]

But it is giving below error. This is the reason I am not able to connect to `DB`.

[image]

Could you please guide me what mistake i am doing. is there any other way to connect. Am I doing some mistake in database?

[image]

Comment: If you manually try to ssh into your cloud host, is that successful? The error is saying it tried but gave up after 15 seconds waiting

Comment: You spotted it correct Jeff. I am not able to connect to cloud host from putty. Now I undertood the issue is something very different, not related to SQL developer. Thank you @thatjeffsmith

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Hi jeff, I created another DB, now I am getting same issue but different error. Can you please check the same.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341154/error-while-connecting-dbaas-from-sql-developer-able-to-connect-from-putty