# Error while connecting DBaaS from SQl developer. Able to connect from putty

Tags: database, oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Hi I created one `database` in `Oracle cloud`. I am able to connect on the same via `putty`. But I am not able to connect from `sqldeveloper`.

[image]

Below error is coming when I am trying the same.

[image]

Can you please help me on the same

Comment: make sure your ssh key is set to read only privs for your user only, same for the directory, basically chmod 600 the file

Comment: I tried same Jeff. but it did not work. I am still getting same error. @thatjeffsmith

Comment: Just use putty to create a local port fwd and use that as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the port 1521 is already used on your local machine (and so the tunnel isn't getting created) - you can try to select "use specific local port" and to choose another one that could be free.

Edit: please be sure that the private key you're using is in open ssh format. It isn't the same private key that putty uses, the formats aren't compatible.

You can  convert your private key in putty format into openssh format using puttygen: first load your private key, then go to the menu "Convertions > Export Openssh Key"

Regards